# Query on powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell script to capture McAfee AVDate and it give ouput too. But the problem here is, I have added another line in the script where it says, if the McAfee AVDate date is 2 days older than current date, that should show the McAfee AVdate in red color, But that is not working here.

Can anyone help me to correct this please ?

```
 $AVDate = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\McAfee\AVEngine").AVDatDate
$AVDatDate = $AVDate
$thedate = get-date -date $(get-date).adddays(-2) -format yyyy-MM-dd

if($AVDatDate -lt $thedate) {

Add-Content $report "<tr>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=center><B>12</B></td>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=left><B>McAfee AVDate</B></td>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'red'  height='30' align=left><B>$AVDatDate</B></td>"
Add-Content $report "</tr>"

}

else

{

Add-Content $report "<tr>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=center><B>12</B></td>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=left><B>McAfee AVDate</B></td>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Aquamarine'  height='30' align=left><B>$AVDatDate</B></td>"
Add-Content $report "</tr>"

}
```

Comment: because it is never going to the else block. you have to check the date coming from the $avdate and put the condition accordingly

Comment: date is coming in this format "McAfee AVDate 2017/06/21"  , but the color is not changing to red. As the date is 9 days older than current date

Comment: so you explicitly mention the condition in elseif

Comment: Have you checked whether `$AVDatDate` is an actual `DateTime`? It's very likely a string and you have to convert/cast it.

Answer (score 0):

If `$avDate` is "McAfee AVDate 2017/06/21" then

> ```
>  $avDate -lt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-2)
> ```

will always be false because the date will be converted to a string (to match `$avDate`) and a string comparison is done (and digits compare less than letters).

You need to extract and parse the date and compare that. Assuming that format is "yyyy/MM/dd" always then:

```
$d = [DateTime]::ParseExact($avDate.Substring(14), "yyyy'/'MM'/'dd", $null);
```

and then do the date comparison with `$d`.

Comment: I have edited the script like above. but now even one day lesser than the current date the data becoming red. I want only the data to be red when the AVDate is 2days older than current system date..

Comment: @Sandeep Given (as you note in the comments on the question) starts with other text, comparing it to a date will not work. Which is why I extract just the date part in this answer: the call to `Substring`.